# How to upload a Photo on Facebook using Apex?

Tags: upload

I used below code for upload photo on Facebook but I got error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#324) Requires upload
>   file","type":"OAuthException","code":324}}

How can I send photo on facebook?

```
public void uploadPhoto()
{
    HTtpRequest req=new Httprequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    string sss='URL=http://www.vahrehvah.com/indianfood/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/JawaharlalNehru.jpg';
    req.setbody(sss);
    req.setheader('Content-type', '.jpg');
    // req.setheader('Content-type', 'application');
    req.setHeader('Content-length',string.valueof(sss.length()) );
    // req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data' );
    req.setEndpoint('https://graph.facebook.com/455111887925878/photos?access_token='+accesstoken);
    HttpResponse res = null;
    http h= new Http();
    res= h.send(req);
    system.debug('---------message idddddddddddddddddsssssssss---------'+res.getbody());    
}
```